# Github and RDi integration architecture

Tags: git, github, ibm-midrange, rational-developer-for-i

I have a basic question to those who have worked in GitHub and IBMi integration using RDi. I am a beginner to GitHub and was trying to implement GitHub as a version control solution. I have developed a basic workflow:

1. Created a repository in GitHub
2. Cloned that repository in RDi Git perspective
3. Created a new project in iProject perspective
4. Linked that Project to git in RDi
5. Associated that project with IBMi library
6. Created a new branch in Git perspective
7. Transferred some of the sources from IBMi to iProject for testing purpose.
8. Pushed that new branch having the sources to GitHub

Now, as per the above flow, what I understood is that for every new changes I do in iProject, I have to commit those to GitHub to make use of version control. Plus, I have to push the same changes to IBMi server to test and later promote to production.

The problem with this workflow is that I have to manually keep a sync between the IBMi server source code and the GitHub source code to keep track of previous changes. I believe this is not the way other organizations are using GitHub. Can anyone suggest a better architecture wherein the sources I push to GitHub are automatically pushed to IBMi as well so there should be no difference between the two ???
Or if there is any other way that I can link Github directly with my IBMi source library in RDi instead of using iProject?

I have tried the above architecture and somehow I feel that is is not optimized. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Once you push changes to git don't you have to always run git pull on the production server to get the server into sync with the repo on github?   How do other organizations update the production server after changes are pushed to github?  As I understand it, github actions are used to automate the updating of production.